# How to use pointers to point to vector of a struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

```
struct Edge;

struct Node {
    int id;
    vector<Edge> *edges;
};

struct Edge {
    int id;
    Node* vertex1;
    Node* vertex2;
};

int main(){
    vector<Edge> nodeEdgeList;
    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->id = vertex;
    nodePtr->edges = nodeEdgeList;
}
```

I get the following compiler error due to the last line.

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<Edge, std::allocator<Edge> >' to 'std::vector<Edge, std::allocator<Edge> >*' in assignment
```

Comment: If you are trying to construct a geometric entities hierarchy, I suggest you to hold list of pointers (vector<Edge*> EdgeList) not pointer to lists of duplicated objects.

Comment: Agree with Semih Ozmen you should consider modifying your Struct definitions as the intention here is a little odd and not standard form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Node class has a vector * as a member you are trying to set a non pointer to a pointer

The error message is pretty clear here `error: cannot convert 'std::vector<Edge, std::allocator<Edge> >' to 'std::vector<Edge, std::allocator<Edge> >*' in assignment`

so change to:

```
int main(){
    vector<Edge> *nodeEdgeList = new Vector<Edge>;
    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->id = vertex;
    nodePtr->edges = nodeEdgeList;
}
```

or

```
int main(){
    vector<Edge> nodeEdgeList;
    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->id = vertex;
    nodePtr->edges = &nodeEdgeList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){
    vector<Edge> nodeEdgeList;
    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->id = vertex;
    nodePtr->edges = &nodeEdgeList; // <-- use & before
}
```

Comment: Although this answer satifies the needs of quetion, it is error-prone! Here, nodePtr is a dynamic object and possibly exists until it will be destroyed, possibly in another time and function, however &nodeEdgeList will be invalid after this scope ends, because nodeEdgeList will be deleted.